# iOS NSString from UITextField - checking value

Tags: ios, nsstring

In my app I have a dialog box where the user enters some information into a UITextField. Before moving on I need to check that UITextField.text value equals something (the value is captured when the user clicks a submit button). However, my conditional (see below) keeps failing.

```
if (userAssignedName || userAssignedName.length > 0 || ![userAssignedName isEqualToString:@""]) {
 //do something
} else { 
[alertManager showAlert:@"You must enter a name for this OR"];
}
```

When I console log userAssignedName right before the conditional I get what I expect, nothing.

How can I check to make sure the string has value?

Comment: what sort of value you mean only alphabets/number/alphanumeric or any value ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the solution is simple. Either of the 3 values returns a YES/true value.

```
![userAssignedName isEqualToString:@""]
```

This checks if your string is equal to an empty string. (which could be ur default of the textfield?) This is good.

```
userAssignedName.length > 0
```

This checks the chars in your string. This is also fine except you don't need it. It's mostly used for keeping a max number of characters in a textfield.

```
userAssignedName
```

This checks if the actual variable is instantiated. And doesn't and shouldn't involve the userinput in any way. If you remove this your check won't fail.

Solution:

```
if (/*userAssignedName.length > 0 ||*/ ![userAssignedName isEqualToString:@""]) 
{
    //do something
} 
else 
{ 
    [alertManager showAlert:@"You must enter a name for this OR"];
}
```

This should do the trick. And whether or not u use the comment or not is up to you.

Comment: If `userAssignedName` is `nil`, the `if` statement is still true.

Comment: Yes exactly, the object is in existence and thus makes it true. That's exactly what I'm saying. A nil value can be seen as an empty pointer (void*). But still means the object exists (a pointer anyway) and since that is true so is the if-statement since they are all OR-statements in there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
if (userAssignedName || userAssignedName.length > 0 || ![userAssignedName isEqualToString:@""]) {
```

with:

```
if (userAssignedName.length > 0) {
```

You don't want to use:

```
if (![userAssignedName isEqualToString:@""]) {
```

because if `userAssignedName` is `nil`, this `if` statement will succeed when you want it to fail.